# Is 22-23 Celsius (72-73 degrees F) measurably the optimal temperature for office productivity

Tags: environment, productivity

I must admit that I lost the original reference for the claim, but almost certain it was LifeHacker, so it is notable enough.

The claim is that 72-73 degrees Fahrenheit (or about 22-23 Celsius) is THE optimal temperature range for office productivity, with above 74 and below 71 measurably negatively impacting productivity.

Are there unambiguous and uncontested study results proving that there's a measurable (beyond statistical noise) effect?

Comment: This has been asked on Personal Productivity - http://productivity.stackexchange.com/questions/887/how-does-office-temperature-affect-productivity